# Prevent Figlet From Word Wrapping?

Tags: command-line

I am wondering if it is possible to prevent a word wrap in figlet.

I am using it to display the date - time:

```
watch -t -n1 "date +%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S|figlet -p"
```

In my terminal the output is

```
|___ \ / _ \/ |/ _ \       / _ \| ___|       / _ \___ / / _ \ ( _ )     |___ \ 
  __) | | | | | (_) |_____| | | |___ \ _____| | | ||_ \| | | |/ _ \ _____ __) |
 / __/| |_| | |\__, |_____| |_| |___) |_____| |_| |__) | |_| | (_) |_____/ __/ 
|_____|\___/|_|  /_/       \___/|____/       \___/____(_)___/ \___/     |_____|

  ___       ____   ___  
 / _ \     | ___| / _ \ 
| | | |____|___ \| | | |
| |_| |_____|__) | |_| |
 \___/     |____/ \___/
```

I am use to terminal word wrapping text based on the width of terminal.  Some how the word wrap happens between the 2 minute digits.

I know the only thing I know how --- Adding "-p" to figlet.  This had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
watch -t -n1 'figlet $(date +%Y/%-m/%-d) $(date +%-H:%M:%S)'

or

watch -t -n1 'figlet $(date +%Y/%-m/%-d" "%-H:%M:%S)'
```

Comment: This is so close.  It isn't refreshing the date.  It sticks with the date the command is ran.  Tweaking it to <code>watch -n1 "$(date +%Y/%-m/%-d) $(date +%-H:%-M:%-S)"|figlet</code> refreshes, but outputs gibberish.  The text isn't aligned.  Any idea?

Comment: @RonPiggott try my command, instead of piping into figlet. Or for testing, try `figlet $(date +%Y/%-m/%-d) $(date +%-H:%-M:%-S)` by itself. It will show the current date/time... are you expecting something else?

Comment: I tried your command verbatim   It remains at the time the command was executed.  I had included the "watch" so it would be updated once a second.

Comment: fyi: I made a minor change to my time date stanza's, but only for better readability, it doesn't fix your update problem. The entire figlet command is good... but as you say, watch doesn't appear to rerun the command every second. You'll have to play with it I guess. Let me know how you do.

Comment: It doesn't appear to rerun the `date` commands because of the double quoting I think (i.e. the command substitutions get evaluated **once**, by the invoking shell - as you can confirm by using `set -x`). Try single quotes.

Comment: @RonPiggott steeldriver had it right. It's fixed now. Please remember  to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver right you are! Thanks!

Comment: You should invoke `date` only once, with the require format (including the space) present in its format parameter. If you invoke it twice, there's a chance that you'll get incorrect output at midnight.

Comment: @egmont good point. Answer updated.

Comment: @RonPiggott please note the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a `-w` option in [figlet's manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man6/figlet-figlet.6.html) to specify the width. So something like `figlet -w 999` should do the trick.

`-p` seems to influence how figlet handles newlines on *its input*, thus is irrelevant here.

Comment: I would go with `figlet -w $(tput cols) ...`. Using a huge number breaks the output.